# iPad built in dictionary

Tags: iphone, dictionary, ipad

Is the built-in dictionary in iBooks etc available to developers? If so how would I go about using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not available to developers. You could use an open source dictionary [like this one from Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/etext/660), but it might take substantial munging to make it presentable.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I believe the system dictionary is only available through a private API.

*Personal conjecture*: It's one of the many "features" locked away by Apple to separate the iBooks app from 3rd party e-book reader competition. However, at the rate Apple is going, I would expect the API to become public at some point in the next few years.

Comment: Eh, you should remove the 2nd paragraph, that's just some conjecture. It's much more likely that the Dictionary isn't available simply because that API isn't ready yet.

Comment: +1, lol. That's entirely true. Labeled the paragraph as such :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that it might be a copyright issue. I had the same problem about a year ago and not much has changed since then.

My solution was to embed an offline dictionary inside my app and I later turned it into a static library that others can use (for a small fee). If you're looking for a full-blown dictionary you can check it out at [www.lexicontext.com](http://www.lexicontext.com/)

If you just need a spell checker, you can also use UITextChecker